# Run a function from within a each loop (ajax.response)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, each, getjson

I'm having problems trying to pass data to a function from within a each loop. I've roughly pasted my code below. Basically functionA gets JSON data, passes the response to functionB. I want to then pass each response item to functionC so they can be added to an array to plot markers using google maps. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
if(app == undefined) var app = {};

app.Application = function() {

this.functionA = function(){
        var self = this;

        var urlHash = location.hash;
    accessToken = urlHash.split('=')[1];

    if (!accessToken) { 
        return false; 
    } else {
        $.getJSON(instaAPIuri+"users/" + id + "/media/recent?access_token=" + accessToken + "&callback=?", self.functionB);
    };

};

this.functionB = function(response){
    var self = this;

    //Error codes
    if (response.meta.code == 400) {
        alert(response.meta.error_message);
    }

    //Create picture elements with basic information and image
    $.each(response.data, function (i, item) {

        //If item.location == null, while trying to get geolocation = error
        if (item.location != null) {
            functionC( item.location.latitude, item.location.longitude, item.images.thumbnail.url, item.user.username);
        }

    });

};

this.functionC = function(latitude, longitude, imgurl, user) {
    var self = this;
    var latLngPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    //Create marker with custom assets
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:latLngPosition,
        icon:   new google.maps.MarkerImage(imgurl,
                new google.maps.Size(110, 110),
                new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                new google.maps.Point(32, 32)),
        title: user,
        map:map
    });

    //Push in array to delete later
    markersArray.push(marker);
};

this.init();

};

$(function() {

var app = new app.Application();

});
```

Comment: Perhaps try using self.functionC instead of simply functionC?

Comment: I tried that but self refers to the items in the each loop.        TypeError: self.functionC is not a function

Comment: I've managed to fix it. Had to pass an anonymous callback function to $.getJSON. Also it would fail as I hadn't included my else statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

functionB is being called with the context of the $.ajax() settings object. You could use $.proxy() to change the context to app.Application:

```
  if(app == undefined) var app = {};

app.Application = function() {

this.functionA = function(){
        var self = this;

        var urlHash = location.hash;
    accessToken = urlHash.split('=')[1];

    if (!accessToken) { 
        return false; 
    } else {
        $.getJSON(instaAPIuri+"users/" + id + "/media/recent?access_token=" + accessToken + "&callback=?", $.proxy(self.functionB, self));
    };

};

this.functionB = function(response){
    var self = this;

    //Error codes
    if (response.meta.code == 400) {
        alert(response.meta.error_message);
    }

    //Create picture elements with basic information and image
    $.each(response.data, function (i, item) {

        //If item.location == null, while trying to get geolocation = error
        if (item.location != null) {
            self.functionC( item.location.latitude, item.location.longitude, item.images.thumbnail.url, item.user.username);
        }

    });

};

this.functionC = function(latitude, longitude, imgurl, user) {
    var self = this;
    var latLngPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    //Create marker with custom assets
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:latLngPosition,
        icon:   new google.maps.MarkerImage(imgurl,
                new google.maps.Size(110, 110),
                new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                new google.maps.Point(32, 32)),
        title: user,
        map:map
    });

    //Push in array to delete later
    markersArray.push(marker);
};

this.init();

};

$(function() {

var app = new app.Application();

});
```